# Adding non-primitive typed data as property value in nodes and relationships

Tags: java, properties, neo4j, primitive-types

In neo4j we can add node and relationships with various properties using

```
node.setProperty("NodePropertyName",NodePropertyValue)
relationship.setProperty("EdgePropertyName",EdgePropertyValue)
```

Is there any way by which I can use non-primitive datatypes like MAP , Array or user-defined object as `NodePropertyValue` and `EdgePropertyValue` ?

Or do i need to give all values in `MAP<>` individually as separate properties of `Node` or `Relationship` ?

I tried using

```
node.setProperty("USER_PROPERTIES", GraphNode.getNodeproperties());
where,
GraphNode.getNodeproperties() returns MAP<String,Double>
```

But this is giving me an error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown property type on: {Property1=0.0, Property2=0.0, Property3=0.0, Property4=0.0, Property5=0.0, Property6=0.0, Property7=0.0}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way by which I can use non-primitive datatypes like MAP ,
>   Array or user-defined object as NodePropertyValue and
>   EdgePropertyValue ?

Neo4J allows you to store an array of `String`, or an array of a primitive datatype.

Maps are not supported (yet), but an alternative could be to store the map as a JSON structure (using [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)), or even as an XML structure, using [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed only store primitive values as properties. If you want to store a collection of values (and if you're using Spring), then [DynamicPropertiesContainer](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j/docs/2.1.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/fieldaccess/DynamicPropertiesContainer.html) might be an option. If you want to store custom objects, you probably want to create some related nodes. Use [createRelationshipTo(Node otherNode, RelationshipType type)](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html#createRelationshipTo%28org.neo4j.graphdb.Node,%20org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType%29) to accompish this.